# Spring Data ElasticSearch repository instantiation fails

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to run a Spring Data ElasticSearch repository but I am facing the following issue when the application starts:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:99)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
... 52 more
```

I am using Maven to resolve my dependencies, the project libraries contain `spring-data-elasticsearch` and `spring-data-commons` from the Spring Data Lovelace-M1 release train.

I trimmed the repository definition to its simplest expression:

```
public interface UserRepository
    extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

The configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "my.company.dao", elasticsearchTemplateRef = "elasticSearchTemplate")
public class SearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Client elasticSearchClient() throws UnknownHostException {

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY);
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                    InetAddress.getByName("my.elastic.host"), 9300));

        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticSearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(elasticSearchClient());
    }

}
```

Has anyone had the same issue and, more importantly, how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to the fact that I was still using Spring Framework 4 instead of 5 (the latter is mandatory since Spring Data's Kay release train).

Comment: Why is 5 needed?